# How to implement a search in Jquery grid php

Tags: jqgrid

I want to know how to implement a search in my grid with jquery. I construct the grid. The form of search display when i press the search button in the left below of grid. How to implement to post the data and to implement the search in server side. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

you can for example download demo files from http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6. There are files search.php and search_adv.php inside. The file search_adv.php is an example for "advance seraching" and search.php for the "simple searching". On the demo page http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html you can select "New in version 3.5" and "Advanced Searching". The file search_adv.php corresponds to the backend part of this example.

Comment: Ok thanks but i work in a framework php. the grid is OK . i create a button and when i click it , display the search form . but when i click find in search form the data doesn't send to the controller . I think that is the url???How can i correct it any idea? here is my code :

$("#search").click(function(){

 jQuery("#list").jqGrid('searchGrid', {
 sopt:['cn','bw','eq','ne','lt','gt','ew'],
 url:"http://url.local/gc/kerko",
 
 
 } ); 
 
 
 });

Comment: Probably you should only have no errors in your code: `url:"http://url.local/gc/kerko", }` should be replaced to `url:"http://url.local/gc/kerko" }` (no ',' before '}'). Also look at the "Integrations" / "Live Data Manipulation" code from the demo page http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html